Intel wifi driver not detecting Ubuntu 20.04 kernel 15
Intel wifi Ax211 wifi driver is not detecting in Ubuntu 20.04 kernel 15,in documentation on Intel its mentioned it supports 14+ kernel.

Only some of the devices are supported in kernel 5.15 or there is a firmware issue
